# Snippets only working when preceeded by space

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, snippets

I have created my snippets in `texmath.snippets` as:

```
priority -50 

snippet \d "dot" Aw
\dot{$1}
endsnippet

snippet ^^ "superscript" A
^{$1}
endsnippet

snippet __ "subscript" A 
_{$1}
endsnippet
```

The problem is, `^^` and `__`  works only when preceeded by a space, like `w`  options in Ultisnips. But, as you can see, there is no `w`, so this should not be in word limit.

But, still, in latex, `$H__$` doesn't expands to `$H_{}$`, while `$H __$` does properly.

What I am doing wrong here?

I am using `Ultisnips` as snippet engine. This `texmath.snippets` structure is following `honza/snippets`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the `i` option. This is in the help page:

```
   i   In-word expansion - By default a snippet is expanded only if the tab
       trigger is the first word on the line or is preceded by one or more
       whitespace characters. A snippet with this option is expanded
       regardless of the preceding character. In other words, the snippet can
       be triggered in the middle of a word.
```

So it should look like that in the end:

```
snippet ^^ "superscript" Ai
^{$1}
endsnippet

snippet __ "subscript" Ai
_{$1}
endsnippet
```